# How to pass value from one component to another component in Angular2?

Tags: angular

I am trying to pass a value from one component to another in Angular2. So for example, I am trying to implement a component and set a data and title in that component and pass that data and title to another component which is embedded in it?

**Here is the code to better explain.**

```
<cst-multiselect [title]="Countries" [data] = ['one', 'two', three']></cst-multiselect>
```

I am trying to pass the values '***title***' and '***data***' to another component:

```
<div ngbDropdown class="d-inline-block" [autoClose]="false"> 
         <button class="btn btn-outline-primary" id="dropdownMenu1" ngbDropdownToggle>Selected Countries 
</button> 
            <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1"> 
                   <cst-checkbox></cst-checkbox> 
            </div> 
</div>
```

I would like to display the data I passed from cst-multiselect on cst-checkbox(which is a dropdownbox). I would like to set the value and also the data in this dropdownbox. Any help would really be appreciated as I have been trying out multiple methods but to no avail. Thank you!

Comment: What is `"Selected-Countries"` supposed to be. Seems you're subtracting `Countries` from `Selected` ;-)

Comment: We have no way of knowing how `<cst-multiselect>` and `<cst-checkbox>` are related. What does "embedded" mean exactly? Please add more code to your question.

Comment: Hi @GünterZöchbauer, I apologize for the ambuigity.

<cst-multiselect> is actually a dropdown box which contains <cst-checkbox> which is a checkbox component. Basically I am trying to insert this checkbox data into the dropdown box.

So basically inside the <cst-multiselect> html page, I have the following code. (Sorry i will put the code in the next comment)

Comment: `<div ngbDropdown class="d-inline-block" [autoClose]="false">
      <button class="btn btn-outline-primary" id="dropdownMenu1" ngbDropdownToggle>Selected Countries
      </button>
      <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">

              <cst-checkbox></cst-checkbox>

            </div> 
            
      </div>`

Comment: please edit your question and add the code there. Code in comments us unreadable.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer Sorry for the unreadable code. I have edited the qn :)

Comment: I think my answer below still holds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@Component({
  selector: 'cst-multiselect',
  template: '<cst-checkbox [title]="title" [data]="data"'
  ...
})
class CstMultiSelect {
  @Input() title:string;
  @Input() data:string[];
}

@Component({
  selector: 'cst-checkbox',
  ...
})
class CstCheckbox {
  @Input() title:string;
  @Input() data:string[];
}
```