# Angular2 - Pass value between Components

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, angular2-template, angular2-services

app component.ts

```
import { Component,Input } from '@angular/core';

    @Component({
      selector: 'app-root',
      templateUrl: `
      <app-navigation></app-navigation>
      <router-outlet></router-outlet>`,
    })
    export class AppComponent {


      constructor( ) {
      }



    }
```

then this component () is loaded dynamically via a route to display adverts, so I dont actually declare it alongside the  component, I understand how to pass input and outputs using event emitter.. more on this at the end:

```
import { Component, OnInit, Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-ad-page',
  template: `
            <a (notify)="onNotify($event)">CLICKME</a>
  `
})

export class ListAdvertsComponent implements OnInit {

    @Output() notify: EventEmitter<string> = new EventEmitter<string>();

    onClick() {
      this.notify.emit('Click from parralel component');
    }

    constructor(  ) {

    }

    ngOnInit() {
    }

}
```

and finally the  component which is declared in the app.component template

```
  import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
  import { AngularFire, AuthProviders, FirebaseListObservable } from 'angularfire2';
  import { Router } from '@angular/router';

  @Component({
    selector: 'app-navigation',
    template: `
          <header class="mast-head">
          </header>
    `,
  })
  export class NavigationComponent  {


    onNotify(message:string):void {
      alert(message);
    }

    constructor( ) {

    }



  }
```

So I know that you could pass the values to the app-navigation by ammending the selector with something like this  but as I dont actually place this selector in a template (its loaded dynamically into the dom when the user clicks the ad page) so how can I pass variables in an out out of it ? very stuck on this and its not the first time I have been hit with it in angular2 so I would love to hear how people are doing this kind of advanced input output stuff

Comment: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html#!#bidirectional-service

Comment: They are not necessarily parent and child though, they are parallel except one is static and the other is loaded via the router outlet

Comment: Just use a shared service as explained in the tutorial.

Comment: It still uses the child within the parent.. I am looking to see how a random component can share values with another random component

Comment: As Gunter said you need to create a service, just read the docs https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html

Comment: I might add that the tutorial still doesnt really work for my uses, it subscribes the the component but when you navigate away it does not resubscribe again.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to pass value from one component to another component in Angular2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39849994/how-to-pass-value-from-one-component-to-another-component-in-angular2)