# get value from another component angular 4

Tags: angular

I have two separate components; a header component containing a select search box, stats component that shows the results depending on the value of the select box, I was wondering if it's possible to refresh the results once the select box change, I thought about using the `LocalStorage` but it seems like a lazy solution.

Comment: **Services** are here for that, there's plenty of tutorials out here ;)
With **RxJs** you'll be able to keep them synchronized

Comment: can you please elaborate how i can do that Thank you

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to pass value from one component to another component in Angular2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39849994/how-to-pass-value-from-one-component-to-another-component-in-angular2)

Comment: thank you but i don't think the concept of input and output would work here since they are seperate component

Comment: @AyoubIdelhoussain input concept will work... see my solution below.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Use Shared Services:

**Service:**

```
@Injectable()
export class MyService {
    myMethod$: Observable<any>;
    private myMethodSubject = new Subject<any>();

    constructor() {
        this.myMethod$ = this.myMethodSubject.asObservable();
    }

    myMethod(data) {
        console.log(data); // I have data! Let's return it so subscribers can use it!
        // we can do stuff with data if we want
        this.myMethodSubject.next(data);
    }
}
```

**Component1 (sender):**

```
export class SomeComponent {
    public data: Array<any> = MyData;

    public constructor(private myService: MyService) {
        this.myService.myMethod(this.data);
    }
}
```

**Component2 (receiver):**

```
export class SomeComponent2 {
    public data = {};

    public constructor(private myService: MyService) {
        this.myService.myMethod$.subscribe((data) => {
                this.data = data; // And he have data here too!
            }
        );
    }
}
```

[Check documentation!](https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#parent-and-children-communicate-via-a-service)

Comment: Can this exemple work when the select box change the value searched changes ?

Comment: It works with any type of data. You just need to trigger a method and pass data. Which method you trigger or which data you pass is not an issue

Answer (score 6):

The best way is to send the data to the component.

Use the `@Input` property to send the data to the controller. Then implement `ngOnChanges` and execute the function to load the data.

```
import { Component, Input, OnChanges, SimpleChanges } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'second-component',    
})

@Injectable()
export class SecondComponent implements OnChanges {

    @Input()
    selectValue: string;

    ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
           if (changes['selectValue']) {
             //call your function to load the data
           }
    }
    
}
```

uses

```
<second-component [selectValue]="bindYourValue"></second-component>
```

Comment: But how would you set the selectValue from another component?

Answer (score 0):

I think that the best for your case would be to use `service` for communication between components.

Check out example in Angular documentation: https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#parent-and-children-communicate-via-a-service