# Communication between 2 components through service doesn't working

Tags: angular, angular-services

I need help with this. I want send a variable from component to another component via shared service. I have got inspired by [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45186891/9958724), but in the receiver component the "nevim" value is still undefined and I don't know why. Thanks a lot.

**Edit:** Ok, I discovered the problem, it was that the Sender and Receiver component were not using the same instance of service.

**So if you try this in your own project it should be working.**

**Service:**

```
customNevim$: Observable<string>;
private customNevimSubject = new Subject<string>();

constructor() {
    this.customNevim$ = this.customNevimSubject.asObservable();
}

customNevim(data) {
    this.customNevimSubject.next(data);
}
```

**Sender Component:**

```
 message2: string = "test";

 public constructor( private myService: MyService) {
     this.myService.customNevim(this.message2);
 }
```

**Reciever component:**

```
nevim: string;

public constructor( private myService: MyService) {
    this.myService.customNevim$.subscribe((data) => {
                    this.nevim = data; 
                    //after I try console.log "this.nevim" it still shows it as undefined
                }
}
```

Comment: Post a complete minimal example, as a stackblitz, reproducing the problem. Where and when you log, where and when you call the service and where and when the components are created is a critical information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.. Change

```
this.customNevim$ = this.customNevimSubject.asObservable();
```

to nothing in constructor and your observable should be

Non rxjs6 -->  `this.customNevim$ = Observable.from(this.customNevimSubject);`
`import "rxjs/add/observable/from";`

Rxjs6 -->`this.customNevim$ = from(this.customNevimSubject);`

Rrxjs6 --> import from `import { from } from 'rxjs';`

Updating your example...

**Service**

```
private customNevimSubject = new BehaviourSubject<string>("TestBehaviour");
customNevim$: Observable<string> = Observable.from(this.customNevimSubject);

constructor(){}

customNevim(data) {
  this.customNevimSubject.next(data);
}
```

**Sender Component**

```
 message2: string = "test";

 constructor(private myService: MyService){}

 ngOnInit(){
   this.myService.customNevim(this.message2);
 }
```

**Reciever Component**

```
nevim: string;

constructor(private myService: MyService){}

ngOninit(){
       this.myService.customNevim$.subscribe((data) => {
         /// Log the data
         console.log(data);
       }
}
```

Comment: The nonRXJS works but still undefined output and withRXJS the import shows error "has not exported member 'from'"

Comment: They are both rxjs, one is rxjs6 if you're using angular 6 without rxjs-compat then you must import from via import "rxjs/add/observable/from"; Also remove all your code in your component from your constructor and move it to ngOnInit(). The service you shouldn't have anything in the constructor. Also, console log the data, and not this.nevim to see if you are actually getting the data.

Comment: tried it, but still the same and the "console.log(data)" in receiver component is not even fired so the problem must be there.

Comment: add logs in your service and see if you are getting the right data across your components/services. Before updating the observable. Also, you could be getting undefined because you're using a Subject which is not going to send anything until you update it via your sender component first, and then listen via reciever component.

Comment: yea, as I said in other comment, when i try log the customNevim in service i get the right value which is "test". So that's propably not the problem. And could you please update the answer how I could update it via sender (and then listen via receiver...)?

Comment: hmmm, are you subscribing in the reciever component after sending the test variable via sender? if you are, then change from subject to ReplaySubject, which will replay the last obs sent. Or Behaviour subject which will always send a default value.

Comment: yes im doing that. When I change it to ReplaySubject it doesn't help and when I change it to Behaviour subject it works but it shows the default value everytime. And that's not really useful, because I need some variable to send and not only the default value.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

Service:

```
customNevim$: Observable<string>;
private customNevimSubject = new Subject<string>();

constructor() {
    this.customNevim$ = this.customNevimSubject.asObservable();
}

customNevim(data) {
    this.customNevimSubject.next(data);
}
```

Sender Component:

```
message2: string = "test";

 public constructor( private myService: MyService) {

 }

 ngOnInit() {
   this.myService.customNevim(this.message2);
}
```

Reciever component:

```
nevim: string;

public constructor( private myService: MyService) {

}

ngOnInit() {
    this.myService.customNevim$.subscribe((data) => {
         this.nevim = data; 
    });
}
```

Comment: And where should I use the sendMsg() method?

Comment: The place where u want to trigger the msg functionality, so observers can receieve it. or else you can move that logic to ngOnInit().

Comment: I don't know where should I place it, i just want to have "nevim" in receiver component have value of the "message2" in sender component.

Comment: Tried it, but still the same output :( the sender component works, because when i try log the "data" in service method customNevim it shows the right value, but in receiver still undefined

Comment: Is service is singleton and declared in app.module?

Comment: yes, it is declared. also when i try log "it works!" in the subscribe method in receiver component, it won't show, so the problem is that its not executed.