# How to control the variable to show/hide in different components in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

There are 3 components in my example:

First component:

A.component.ts:
The parent component - where I am making an HTTP call and getting the response.

```
const res = this.http.post("https://api.com/abcde", {
  test: true,
});

res.subscribe((res) => {
   this.itemID = res.item.id; // I am able to get this ID
});
```

Second Component:

B.component.html: This is the page where I want to show that show/hide the content.

```
<app-ab-test [showMe]></app-ab-test>
```

Third Component:

ab-test.component.ts: This is the actual component used in b.component.html

```
@Input() public showMe = false;
```

ab-test.component.html:

```
<div *ngIf="showMe">
 <img>
</div>
```

so it would be great if we can connect the `this.itemID` to control the `showMe` boolean value.

I am still learning and able to make it work until here, your help in helping me understand will be a great help.

Comment: it must be: `<app-ab-test [showMe]="your_variable"></app-ab-test>`

Comment: Better use a service and declare a public variable within service. Sort of GlobalService, which holds all the global variables and methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

actually you need to read more about @Input , @Output , @ViewChild 
to get data from 2 component parent & child 
if you need send data between 2 different component (not parent or child) you can Use Shared Service

[get value from another component angular 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45186469/get-value-from-another-component-angular-4)

Comment: Thank you so much for this answer, was able to successfully implement my call in the service and was able to subscribe it across the project to get the results, Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to pass data with [`@Input`](https://angular.io/api/core/Input) Decorator then the name should be the same:

For example:

if you passing data like:

```
<app-ab-test [showBanner]="true"></app-ab-test>
```

then in ab-test TS code must be:

```
@Input() public showBanner;
```

and ab-test HTML will be:

```
<div *ngIf="showBanner">
  <img />
</div>
```

Comment: Also, my bad I already did that using the variable value in second.html - but I wanted the value from response of this.itemID to control the boolean value of showMe

Comment: Then you can implement Service to share the data as commented by Guruprasad! which will every time emit the latest value

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
-- In a Second Component html
<app-ab-test [showBanner]="showMe"></app-ab-test>

-- In a Second Component ts
showMe = true;

-- In a Third Component.ts
@Input() public showBanner;

-- In a Third Component.html
<div *ngIf="showBanner">
 <img>
</div>
```

Comment: Also, my bad I already did that using the variable value in second.html - but I wanted the value from response of ```this.itemID``` to control the boolean value of ```showMe```